# How to change a line Symbol layer type using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Inxfj.png)

[image]

I need to change a line style from Simple Line to Marker Line, and after that, use it as an arrow and change it's rotation and colors using PyQGIS.

Comment: What did you try so far, did you already started with some code and encountered an error? Please specify your problema nd have a look to https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/

Comment: Actually, I have no idea about how to do this using PyQgis. I made 'by hand', but I need to automate the process. It's arrows to show flow directions, based on a Digital Elevation Model. I already have the line slopes, and I also need to show which side they are going.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here a standalone recipe. We've seen you are using "Rule-based" symbology. Instead of doing the case for this particular case, we've made the sample for "Single Symbol" and at the end made the transformation to "Rule-based" symbology

```py
iface.addVectorLayer('https://d2ad6b4ur7yvpq.cloudfront.net/naturalearth-3.3.0/ne_50m_rivers_lake_centerlines.geojson', 'Rivers lake centerlines', 'ogr')
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# We apply the recipe to QgsSingleSymbolRenderer ("Single Symbol")
simpleMarkerSymbolLayer = QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayer()
simpleMarkerSymbolLayer.setShape(QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayer.Arrow)
property = QgsProperty()
property.setExpressionString("45 * 2")
property.setActive(True)
simpleMarkerSymbolLayer.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyAngle, property)

propertyColor = QgsProperty()
propertyColor.setExpressionString("if(attribute( 'scalerank' ) > 3, 'red', 'green')")
propertyColor.setActive(True)
simpleMarkerSymbolLayer.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyFillColor, propertyColor)

markerSymbol = QgsMarkerSymbol([simpleMarkerSymbolLayer])
# markerSymbol.setAngle(90.0) # Commented as we already set dynamically angle from an expression

markerLineSymbolLayer = QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayer()
markerLineSymbolLayer.setColor(QColor('#00ff00'))
markerLineSymbolLayer.setSubSymbol(markerSymbol)
lineSymbol = QgsLineSymbol([markerLineSymbolLayer])
layer.renderer().setSymbol(lineSymbol)

# Convert to rule based renderer ("Single Symbol" to "Rule-based")
# If not required, just comment below two lines and keep the last line
newRenderer = QgsRuleBasedRenderer.convertFromRenderer(layer.renderer())
layer.setRenderer(newRenderer)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: Nice. And how can I pass an expression in setAngle() as a parameter? I mean, it's gonna be flow direction arrows, and the angle needs to be variable, according with the difference between each line altitude.

Comment: Updated answer to account with expression for angle

Comment: Perfect. Another question that came to me is that I have an expression for the colors as well,     color = 'case\r\nwhen  \"MDT\" > \"Z1\" then color_rgb(255,0,0)\r\nwhen  \"MDT\" < \"Z1\" then color_rgb(0,0,255)\r\nend'    How can I use this expression to set the arrows colors?

Comment: Updated my answer again. If you need to change other properties for the same symbol using expressions , look at https://qgis.org/api/classQgsSymbolLayer.html#a0311dd1ecd478294cb3b0ff3eb694a57

Comment: Hi @ThomasG77, I was wondering if you could maybe have a look at my other question I placed on Stack recently? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380599/is-there-a-easy-way-to-add-graduated-symbology-to-created-arrows-using-pyqgis I am facing a similar issue. And you seem to be the only expert I can find regarding this specific topic.