# Using an IF statement to change colors for layers using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

How to change the colors according the values in 'C_index' field?

I tried a `for` loop, in order to read all values in this field, and an `if` statement to set all 'red' and 'blue' values to the same colors. But it keeps returning me just one color, the first one in the loop, as shown in the image below.

Here's the entire code:

```
iface.addVectorLayer('E:/Bkp/Programacao/Python/Declividade_linhas/Linhas_pontos.shp', '', 'ogr')
layer = iface.activeLayer()

exp = 'case\r\nwhen  \"MDT\" > \"Z1\" then angle_at_vertex($geometry, 1)- 0\r\nwhen  \"MDT\" < \"Z1\" then angle_at_vertex($geometry, 1)- 180\r\nend' 

simpleMarkerSymbolLayer = QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayer()
simpleMarkerSymbolLayer.setShape(QgsSimpleMarkerSymbolLayer.Arrow)
property = QgsProperty()
property.setExpressionString(exp)
property.setActive(True)
simpleMarkerSymbolLayer.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsSymbolLayer.PropertyAngle, 
property)
markerSymbol = QgsMarkerSymbol([simpleMarkerSymbolLayer])
markerSymbol.setSize(7)

markerLineSymbolLayer = QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayer()
markerLineSymbolLayer.setSubSymbol(markerSymbol)
markerLineSymbolLayer.setPlacement(4)

#set colors
for f in layer.getFeatures():
    if f['C_index'] == 'blue':
        markerLineSymbolLayer.setColor(QColor('blue'))
    else:
        markerLineSymbolLayer.setColor(QColor('red'))

lineSymbol = QgsLineSymbol([markerLineSymbolLayer])
layer.renderer().setSymbol(lineSymbol)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

[image: returning just one color]

Comment: Edited on the other side e.g https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/366133/how-to-change-a-line-symbol-layer-type-using-pyqgis Wanted you to find your way by yourself to improve your learning but as you seem to be stuck.

Comment: You're right, I'm a little stuck yet, still learning python and PyQgis. But I understood the code, thanks a lot.