# Adding graduated symbology to created arrows using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, symbology

I would like to add graduated Symbology to my custom created arrows. Unfortunately it does not seem to work. When manually creating graduated symbology the steps are rather easy.

Could someone help me with this last step?

[image]

And this is what I would like to see eventually:

[image]

And my code I created so far:

```
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer,
    QgsSingleSymbolRenderer,
    QgsLineSymbol,
    QgsFillSymbol,
    QgsProject,
    QgsRectangle,
    QgsArrowSymbolLayer,
    QgsMultiRenderChecker,
    QgsProperty,
    QgsSymbolLayer,
    QgsMapSettings,
    QgsSymbol
)


layer = QgsVectorLayer( "?query=SELECT from_country, ubc_processing_plant, delivered_tonnes_2019, make_line(Centroids_countries.geometry, UBC_processing_2030.geometry) FROM ubc_flows JOIN Centroids_countries ON ubc_flows.from_country = Centroids_countries.NUTS_NAME JOIN UBC_processing_2030 ON ubc_flows.ubc_processing_plant = UBC_processing_2030.name", "vlayer", "virtual" )
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

def test_3(self):
        sym = self.renderer().symbol()
        
        shape_sym = QgsGeometryGeneratorSymbolLayer.create({'geometryModifier': 'difference(difference(make_line(start_point($geometry), centroid(offset_curve($geometry, length($geometry)/-10.0)), end_point($geometry)), buffer(start_point($geometry), 10000)), buffer(end_point( $geometry), 10000))', 'outline_color': 'black', 'symbolType': '1'})
        shape_sym.setSymbolType(QgsSymbol.Line)
        
        arrow = QgsArrowSymbolLayer.create(
            {
                "arrow_width": "3",
                "head_length": "3",
                "head_thickness": "3",
                "head_type": "0",
                "arrow_type": "0",
                "is_curved": "1",
                "arrow_start_width": "3"
            }
        )
        
        shape_sym.subSymbol().changeSymbolLayer(0, arrow)
        sym.changeSymbolLayer(0, shape_sym)
        
        
        vals = []
        fld = 'delivered_tonnes_2019'
        for f in self.getFeatures():
            vals.append(int(f[fld]))

        colors = ['#fffff4', '#fcfdce', '#ffffbf', '#abdda4', '#2b8300']

        vals = list(filter(None, vals))
        vals = [float(s) for s in vals]
        lower = float((sorted(vals))[0])
        upper = float((sorted(vals))[-1])
        step = (upper-lower)/len(colors)
        range_list = []
        for c in colors:
            cat = [lower, lower+step, c]
            sym = QgsSymbol.defaultSymbol(self.geometryType())
            sym.setColor(QColor(cat[2]))
            rng = QgsRendererRange(cat[0], cat[1], sym, '{0:.1f}-{1:.1f}'.format(cat[0], cat[1]))
            range_list.append(rng)
            lower = (lower+step)

        renderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer(fld, range_list)
        # Convert to rule based renderer ("Single Symbol" to "Rule-based")
        # If not required, just comment below two lines and keep the last line
        newRenderer = QgsGraduatedSymbolRenderer.convertFromRenderer(self.renderer())
        self.setRenderer(newRenderer)
        self.triggerRepaint()

test_3(layer)
```

Comment: @ThomasG77 could you maybe have a look at this question?